# Android Studio problems when starting new project

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time i would start a new Android Studio project, i would always have some rendering errors ( the Hello World that should show when creating a basic Empty Activity was not showing). People who had the same problem would just change the sdk version in the build gradle from 28 to 27, and it worked for me too.

For some reason, this time when i changed back to 27, now Android Studio cannot resolve any symbols. Im talking stuff like it cant resolve symbol `super.OnCreate(...)` and extends `AppCompatActivity` (resolving works fine when in sdk 28, but dosent show the Hello World). I have other projects open, stuff I've cloned from github that are set at SDK 28, and are working fine. But starting a new project from my own Android Studio is not going well for me.

I've never liked going back to version 27 for no reason, so now that i cant even do that, anyone have any solutions ?

Comment: You could try doing a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED WITH COMPLETE REINSTALL OF ANDROID STUDIO!